# Como realizar una consulta mas rápida MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, revisión-de-código

Hola que tal? estoy tratando de realizar una consulta de base de datos (MYSQL) y necesito optimizarla para que sea lo mas rápido que sea posible, por ahora he bajado de 2 segundos a 1.27, y aun sigue siendo lento, Aquí van las tablas que están dentro de la consulta:

Tabla precios

```
CREATE TABLE `precios` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `porcentaje` DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `precio` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `precio2` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `ganancia` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `costo` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `idproducto` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `numerodepreciodelista` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `impuesto` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `ingresosbrutos` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `idproducto`)
)
```

Tabla codigobarras

```
CREATE TABLE `codigobarras` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `idproducto` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `codigobarras` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `idrubro` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `idpromocion` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Tabla categoriasdeproductos

```
CREATE TABLE `categoriadeproductos` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nombre` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `ganancia` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Tabla proveedores

```
CREATE TABLE `proveedores` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nombre` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `descripcion` TEXT NULL,
    `domicilio` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `localidad` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `telefono` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `fax` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `codigo postal` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `contacto` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Tabla productos

```
    CREATE TABLE `productos` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nombre` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `categoria` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `proveedor` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `cantidad` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `cantidadbultoabierto` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `cantidadbultocerrado` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `stockminimo` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '4.00',
    `fecha` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `codigobarras` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `imagen` BLOB NULL,
    `eliminado` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `especial` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ingresosbrutos` DECIMAL(3,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `tipodeproducto` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ultimamodificacion` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `id` (`id`),
    INDEX `nombre` (`id`)
)
```

Ahora la consulta que estoy haciendo es la siguiente

```
SELECT productos.id, productos.nombre as Nombre
, categoriadeproductos.nombre AS Categoria
, proveedores.nombre AS Proveedor 
, cantidad as Cantidad
, stockminimo AS 'Stock Mínimo'
, (precios.precio) AS Precio
, (precios.precio2) AS 'Precio %'
, (precios.costo) AS 'P. costo'
, (precios.ganancia) AS Ganancia
, ultimamodificacion AS 'Fecha última modificación'
, (select codigobarras.codigobarras From codigobarras WHERE codigobarras.idproducto = productos.id LIMIT 1) AS 'Código de Barras' 
FROM productos INNER JOIN (precios, proveedores, categoriadeproductos) ON  proveedores.id = productos.proveedor AND categoriadeproductos.id = productos.categoria AND precios.idproducto = productos.id WHERE precios.numerodepreciodelista = 0 AND productos.eliminado = 0;
```

Tarda aproximadamente siempre entre 1.2 y 1.3 segundos, El explain de la consulta es la siguiente:

```
+------+--------------------+----------------------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type        | table                | type   | possible_keys     | key     | key_len | ref                             | rows | Extra                                      |
+------+--------------------+----------------------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY            | precios              | ALL    | NULL              | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                            | 2073 | Using where                                      |
|    1 | PRIMARY            | productos            | eq_ref | PRIMARY,id,nombre | PRIMARY | 4       | sistema_tpv2.precios.idproducto |    1 | Using where                                      |
|    1 | PRIMARY            | proveedores          | ALL    | PRIMARY           | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                            |    2 | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)        |
|    1 | PRIMARY            | categoriadeproductos | ALL    | PRIMARY           | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                            |    3 | Using where; Using join buffer (incremental, BNL join) |
|    2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | codigobarras         | ALL    | NULL              | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                            | 1926 | Using where                                      |
+------+--------------------+----------------------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Explicacion de la consulta**

La consulta realiza un listado de todos los productos que se encuentran en la base de datos, Cada producto comprende por una categoria y un proveedor, que se apuntan a las tablas subsiguientes con el ID o Indice de estas, esta parte esta bastante optimizada, pero la complicacion esta con los precios, cada producto tiene  un costo, un precio, un precio fraccionario (precio2), una ganancia basado en el costo (ganancia), y en la tabla precios, existe el campo IDPRODUCTO es el que hace referencia al producto, y por cada producto pueden haber varios precios. Cada precio se los identifica por NUMERODEPRECIODELISTA, por defecto es 0 que es el basico, y en la consulta solo me interesa mostrar este. entonces en el WHERE coloco numerodepreciosdelista = 0. Y finalmente por cada producto existe un codigo de barra (codigobarras) que puede haber mas de uno por cada producto, y por tal razon lo tengo que limitar a 1, como esta en la consulta, cada codigo de barra hace referencia al producto por el campo IDPRODUCTO.
En la consulta utilize inner join, como se puede ver, pero no logro optimizarlo mas de 1.20 seg. Espero encontrar una forma mas optima! gracias desde ya

ACLARACIóN:
Todas las Tablas son secundarias a Productos. 
*Tablas secundarias:*

### Codigobarras

Codigobarras  contiene el código de barra de producto.
El campo idproducto hace referencia a el id de cada producto
Puede haber mas de un código de barra por producto, es decir que un producto puede tener mas de un código de barras.

### Precios

precios contiene los precios de cada producto
El campo idproducto hace refederncia al id de producto
los precios tienen que tener como condicion numerodepreciodelista = 0, porque los demas precios no me interesan en esta consulta.

### Categorias

Cada producto tiene una categoria, y en la tabla de productos hace referencia el campo categoria al id de la categoria a la que pertenece

### proveedores

Al igual que categorias, cada producto pertenece a un proveedor y cada provedoor lleva un id, y el campo proveedor hace referencia a este.

En proveedores y categorias solo hay 3 registros por cada tabla
en precios y codigo de barras hay la misma cantidad de registros que productos, tal vez mas
y productos tiene 2800 registros

Aqui el sql de base que tengo [file.sql](https://paste.ee/p/YTMSe)

Comment: Pudiste al menos tabular el resultado del EXPLAIN... ¿Está leyendo 2073 filas en la tabla `precios` y 1926 filas en la tabla `codigobarras`? Si es así, no es tan _genial_ ni tan _eficiente_ como comenta @r84. Creo que deberías escribir tu consulta de otro modo y agregar algunos índices a tus tablas. ¿Cuál es la estructura de la tabla `codigobarras`y por qué intentas traer campos desde ella usando un SELECT aparte y no haciendo `JOIN` como haces con las demás tablas?

Comment: Ya acomodelos datos, disculpa, y coloque la estructura de codigobarras, estoy leyendo muchas filas en tablas y codigobarras, es verda, pero no se como encontrarle la vuelta para que sea mas eficiente la consulta, yo estoy aprendiendo mysql, no se como limitar de otra forma las consultas sobre cada idproducto en codidobarras asi que tuve que hacerlo de esa forma, no conozco otra, Que indices agregarias tu? yo he agregado y quitado y no encuentro la vuelta.

Comment: Para poder ayudarte, ¿podrías decirme el número de elementos que tiene cada tabla u ordenarme de menor a mayor las tablas por su contenido? Gracias :)

Comment: acabo de hacer una aclaración en la pregunta, donde coloco esa información, espero que sea suficiente. Desde ya gracias

Comment: Acabo de ver que hay relaciones entre tablas con diferentes tipos de datos. Por ejemplo `categoriadeproductos.id = productos.categoria`, en donde `categoriadeproductos.id` es de tipo `INT(11)` y `productos.categoria` es de tipo `CHAR(5)`. También hay errores en tu esquema, como poner como `INDEX` con campo `TEXT` sin indicar la longitud de la clave (sería `INDEX (nombre(8))`). ¿Qué versión de MySQL usas para que no te dé error en tu base de datos? ¿Este es tu esquema real o has hecho modificaciones?

Comment: Por cierto, ¿quieres que te salga el último código de barras agregado a un producto o el primero? (ordenado por su `id` ya que no tiene campo de fecha de actualización o inserción).

Comment: gracias oscar por tu ayuda, si, esta mal el esquema y ya lo arreglo, y sobre el orden de codigobarras, no necesitaría un orden, al ser por id esta bien, muchas gracias desde ya! Utilizo Maria DB 10.12, y ya arregle los esquemas.

Comment: ¿Entonces sigo probando con este esquema o vas a editar tu pregunta para poner el bueno? Estoy reproduciendo tu pregunta aquí: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6A977ygpU7eu7FbtpwzNag/1 por ahora estoy automatizando la inserción de registros en la base de datos para poder hacer medidas de rendimiento posteriormente.

Comment: esta hecho el cambio en la pregunta, ! muchas gracias por tu interes, si quieres te envio un sql a un correo electronico con la base de datos que tengo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La consulta original, en mi máquina de pruebas, dura 1,4 segundos.

La consulta puede mejorarse en dos aspectos:

## Consulta anidada innecesaria

Lo primero que eliminé fue la consulta anidada, por ser innecesaria, ya que una unión de tablas con `INNER JOIN` tiene mayor rendimiento que gestionar una consulta adicional por cada registro obtenido.

```
SELECT productos.id,
       productos.nombre AS Nombre,
       categoriadeproductos.nombre AS Categoria,
       proveedores.nombre AS Proveedor,
       cantidad AS Cantidad,
       stockminimo AS 'Stock Mínimo',
       (precios.precio) AS Precio,
       (precios.precio2) AS 'Precio %',
       (precios.costo) AS 'P. costo',
       (precios.ganancia) AS Ganancia,
       ultimamodificacion AS 'Fecha última modificación',
       codigobarras.codigobarras AS 'Código de Barras'
FROM productos
INNER JOIN precios
    ON precios.numerodepreciodelista = 0 AND precios.idproducto = productos.id 
INNER JOIN codigobarras
    ON codigobarras.idproducto = productos.id
INNER JOIN (proveedores, categoriadeproductos)
ON proveedores.id = productos.proveedor
    AND categoriadeproductos.id = productos.categoria
WHERE productos.eliminado = 0
GROUP BY productos.id
```

Ahora el tiempo de ejecución es de 850 ms. Un 40% menos (casi la mitad).

Pero el `DESCRIBE` es:

```
1       SIMPLE  precios NULL    ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2073    10.00   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1       SIMPLE  productos       NULL    eq_ref  PRIMARY,id,nombre       PRIMARY 4       pruebas.precios.idproducto      1       10.00   Using where
1       SIMPLE  proveedores     NULL    ALL     PRIMARY NULL    NULL    NULL    2       50.00   Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
1       SIMPLE  categoriadeproductos    NULL    ALL     PRIMARY NULL    NULL    NULL    3       33.33   Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
1       SIMPLE  codigobarras    NULL    ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1926    10.00   Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
```

## Índices de tablas

El segundo problema (el más importante) que sufre tu consulta es que se realizan asociaciones entre tablas usando campos que no están indexados, por lo que para encontrarlos hay que recorrer todos los registros de la tabla una y otra vez.

Si agregamos un índice a cada campo relacionado y al `eliminado` (que tiene una relevancia importante en esta consulta):

```
ALTER TABLE `precios` ADD INDEX( `idproducto`);
ALTER TABLE `codigobarras` ADD INDEX(`idproducto`);
ALTER TABLE `productos` ADD INDEX( `eliminado`);
```

Obtendremos una reducción en el tiempo de la consulta a tan sólo 140 ms, un 90% menos que la consulta inicial (una décima parte) y un 84% menos que la mejorada quitando la consulta anidada.

En este caso el `DESCRIBE` nos da:

```
id      select_type     table   partitions      type    possible_keys   key     key_len ref     rows    filtered        Extra
1       SIMPLE  proveedores     NULL    ALL     PRIMARY NULL    NULL    NULL    2       100.00  Using temporary; Using filesort
1       SIMPLE  precios NULL    ALL     idproducto      NULL    NULL    NULL    2073    10.00   Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
1       SIMPLE  productos       NULL    eq_ref  PRIMARY,id,nombre,eliminado     PRIMARY 4       pruebas.precios.idproducto      1       9.98    Using where
1       SIMPLE  categoriadeproductos    NULL    ALL     PRIMARY NULL    NULL    NULL    3       33.33   Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
1       SIMPLE  codigobarras    NULL    ref     idproducto      idproducto      4       pruebas.precios.idproducto      1       100.00  NULL
```

Comment: muchas gracias!

Comment: Resumiendo, es muy importante tener las index adecuadas en la estructura de la base de datos, pues de esta forma el servidor de base de datos encuentra de manera más directa los campos en una consulta

Comment: Es más. Si quieres definir clave foráneas, un requisito es que haga referencia a la clave de otra tabla.

Comment: Y lo de que código de barras exista mas de un registro por idproducto? Cómo se puede limitar?

Answer (score 3):

Te recomiendo busques un poco sobre normalización de datos y las relaciones en MySQL, actualmente estas teniendo algunos problemas con los nombres de campos y que no estas relacionando las tablas ni creando indices para campos como `codigodebarras.idproducto` , o `productos.proveedor` que deberia llamarse en tal caso `idproveedor` por la relación que estas consultando. 
Si agregas indices en los campos por los que relacionas y creas las relaciones correctamente deberia incrementarse la velocidad.

Te adjunto la siguiente Querie para tener un poco mas prolija la consulta y quitando la Subconsulta.

```
SELECT 
pr.id, 
pr.nombre as Nombre,
cp.nombre AS Categoria,
pv.nombre AS Proveedor, 
cantidad as Cantidad,
stockminimo AS 'Stock Mínimo',
(p.precio) AS Precio,
(p.precio2) AS 'Precio %',
(p.costo) AS 'P. costo',
(p.ganancia) AS Ganancia,
ultimamodificacion AS 'Fecha última modificación',
cod.codigobarras AS 'Código de Barras'
FROM productos pr 
INNER JOIN precios p ON p.idproducto = pr.id
INNER JOIN proveedores pv ON pv.id = pr.proveedor 
INNER JOIN categoriadeproductos cp ON cp.id = pr.categoria
INNER JOIN codigobarras cod ON cod.idproducto = pr.id -- Probablemente devuelva mas de un resultados si tenes mas de un Codigo de Barra para un solo producto
WHERE 
p.numerodepreciodelista = 0 AND pr.eliminado = 0;
```

Espero que sirva para aclararte un poco mas tu problema.
Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, como puedo limitar la cantidad de codigos de barra, como me especificas tu, "posiblemente devuelva mas de un resultado ...." como se podia ahcer eso? gracias

Comment: Con la siguiente consulta podras ver cuales tienes repetidos, y en caso de tenerlos deberas elegir con que registro quedarte
`SELECT idproducto, GROUP_CONCAT(codigobarras) 'codigos repetidos'
FROM codigobarras
GROUP BY idproducto
HAVING COUNT(*)>1`