# Problema con relaciones en DATASET obtenido de base de datos

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Estoy teniendo problemas para poder obtener una tabla con relaciones. El problema me surgió que tenia una consulta compleja con muchas relaciones, al realizar la pregunta me ayudaron a hacer la consulta que sea eficiente y rápida, pero al colocarla en mi programa basado en VB.NET me salió el siguiente error:

```
No se pudieron habilitar las restricciones. Una o varias filas contienen valores que infringen las restricciones NON-NULL, UNIQUE o FOREIGN-KEY.
```

El sistema debe mostrar en pantalla a travez de un datagridview todos los productos, simples palabras pero complejo de realizar.

Tengo realizadas clases para cada cosa, porque el sistema cada vez es mas complejo y he separado todo en clases.

El datagridview utiliza un bindingsource, de la siguiente manera:

```
Public datosdeproductos As New BindingSource
Private listadodeproducto As New DataSet
datosdeproductos.DataSource = listadodeproducto
Using conexion As New MySqlConnection(conexionstring)
    conexion.Open()
    If listadodeproducto Is Nothing Then
        listadodeproducto = New DataSet()
        listadodeproducto.BeginInit()
    End If
    dim consulta as string = "SELECT pr.id, pr.nombre as Nombre, cp.nombre AS Categoria, pv.nombre AS Proveedor, cantidad as Cantidad, stockminimo AS 'Stock Mínimo', (p.precio) AS Precio, (p.precio2) AS 'Precio %', (p.costo) AS 'P. costo', (p.ganancia) AS Ganancia, ultimamodificacion AS 'Fecha última modificación', cod.codigobarras AS 'Código de Barras' FROM productos pr INNER JOIN precios p ON p.idproducto = pr.id INNER JOIN proveedores pv ON pv.id = pr.proveedor INNER JOIN categoriadeproductos cp ON cp.id = pr.categoria INNER JOIN codigobarras cod ON cod.idproducto = pr.id WHERE p.numerodepreciodelista = 0 AND pr.eliminado = 0;"
    Using adaptador As New MySqlDataAdapter(consulta, conexion)
        adaptador.Fill(listadodeproducto, "listadodeproductos")
    End using
    conexion.close
End using
planillalistadeproductos.datasource = listadodeproducto ' 
planillalistadeproductos es el datagridview
planillalistadeproductos.DataMember = "listadodeproductos"
```

La consulta que estoy utilizando es la siguiente:

```
SELECT 
pr.id, 
pr.nombre as Nombre,
cp.nombre AS Categoria,
pv.nombre AS Proveedor, 
cantidad as Cantidad,
stockminimo AS 'Stock Mínimo',
(p.precio) AS Precio,
(p.precio2) AS 'Precio %',
(p.costo) AS 'P. costo',
(p.ganancia) AS Ganancia,
ultimamodificacion AS 'Fecha última modificación',
cod.codigobarras AS 'Código de Barras'
FROM productos pr 
INNER JOIN precios p ON p.idproducto = pr.id
INNER JOIN proveedores pv ON pv.id = pr.proveedor 
INNER JOIN categoriadeproductos cp ON cp.id = pr.categoria
INNER JOIN codigobarras cod ON cod.idproducto = pr.id -- Probablemente devuelva mas de un resultados si tenes mas de un Codigo de Barra para un solo producto
WHERE 
p.numerodepreciodelista = 0 AND pr.eliminado = 0;
```

Esta consulta es funcional, quiero decir que la ejecuto en la consola del servidor de la base de datos y respondo correctamente sin errores, y de forma rápida, esta consulta es la respuesta de otra pregunta, el link de la pregunta se encuentra abajo.

El dataset, no tiene ninguna tabla cargada hasta el momento, pero después de cargar esta tabla, necesito agregar más, por tanto, no puedo usar datatable, tengo que utilizar si o si un dataset.

Como se ve, en el código, al rellenar el dataset, "listadodeproducto" da el error (No se pudieron habilitar...), he intentado de todo pero no encuentro solución.

Todos los detalles de la consulta están en esta pregunta: [stackoverflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/96048/como-realizar-una-consulta-mas-r%C3%A1pida-mysql)

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Puedes aclarar en la pregunta original cual fue la respuesta que te sirvio?? usa el tilde en la respuesta para marcarla como aceptada. y de paso, saca el query afuera asi podemos analizar cual es el problema

Comment: y ese query en la base de datos, anda?

Comment: pregunta editada!, ese query si anda en la consola del servidor

Comment: probaste haciendo adaptador.Fill(listadodeproducto) directamente?

Comment: no funcionaría porque no carga la tabla en el dataset, me da error, y necesito que si o si sea un dataset, porque mas adelante debo colocarle mas tablas

Comment: ok.. explicame porque eso ultimo.. que necesidad hay que las relaciones las maneje la base de datos?

Comment: si puedes, date una vuelta por el [chat]

Comment: ninguna, por ahora, si podes ver, en ningun momento hago relaciones en la base de datos, en la pregunta anterior dice como es la estructura de la base de datos, y no hay relación entre las tablas, las relaciones se especifican en la consulta, la consulta tiene relaciones entre las tablas. Es ahi donde, yo creo, se crean relaciones en la consulta, porque la base de datos no tiene relaciones

Comment: no encuentro solución al problema! si lo encuentro publico obviamente, por favor alguien sabe a que se debe el error?

Comment: Tuve el mismo problema con las consultas, al cargar el Datatable() con el MYSQL Reader, generaba el error NON-NULL, UNIQUE o FOREIGN-KEY. Al final lo resolví cambiando la versión de MySQL Connector.NET. https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si a alguien le sucede! este problema lo solucione de la siguiente forma

```
SELECT productos.id,
       productos.nombre AS Nombre,
       categoriadeproductos.nombre AS Categoria,
       proveedores.nombre AS Proveedor,
       cantidad AS Cantidad,
       stockminimo AS 'Stock Mínimo',
       (precios.precio) AS Precio,
       (precios.precio2) AS 'Precio %',
       (precios.costo) AS 'P. costo',
       (precios.ganancia) AS Ganancia,
       ultimamodificacion AS 'Fecha última modificación',
       codigobarras.codigobarras AS 'Código de Barras'
FROM productos
INNER JOIN precios
    ON precios.numerodepreciodelista = 0 AND precios.idproducto = productos.id 
INNER JOIN codigobarras
    ON codigobarras.idproducto = productos.id
INNER JOIN (proveedores, categoriadeproductos)
ON proveedores.id = productos.proveedor
    AND categoriadeproductos.id = productos.categoria
WHERE productos.eliminado = 0
GROUP BY productos.id
```

En simples palabras he quitado las tablas para realizar la consulta virtualmente, y lo mas importante he agregado indices KEY en cada identificador de las tablas relacionadas a las que se hacen referencia, y el resultado es simple, y la consulta es mas efectiva! gracias a los que me intentaron ayudar!!