# Optimizar un UPDATECOMMAND de mysql bajo vb.net!

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Hola que tal? estoy trabajando en un programa bajo vb.net, bajo mysql, y al hacer una actualización de datos extensa, se torna muy lento, alrededor de 2 - 15 minutos aproximadamente. Aclaro que no se trata de un DELETE COMMAND ni de INSERT COMMAND, es decir, no hago borrado de registros ni insercion, solo actualización. Los objetos que utilizo son los siguientes:

- Un datagridview llamado listadodeproductos, el cual muestra todos los
  productos de la base de datos a editar, Aclaro que el usuario tiene
  la posibilidad de editar instantaneamente muchos campos, por ejemplo:
  aumentar todos los precios un %10.
- Bindingsource llamado datosdeproductos
- Un datatable llamado listadodeproducto, que contiene los datos cargados de la base de datos
- Un bindingmanagerbase llamado listadepreciosbinding, para poder actualizar los cambios realizados en el control a la DataTable
- Un MySqlDataAdapter llamado adaptador, para realizar la carga y actualización de los datos de datatable y la base de datos
- Una mysqlconnection llamado conexión, llamado a través de la variable conexionstring, del cual no esta mostrado por razones obvias.
- 3 subrutinas de las cuales una, actualizardatos(), es la que se
  llama cuando se terminan de realizar los cambios en el formulario

Los comandos SELECT y UPDATE del "adaptador" son los que importan aquí, el select esta perfecto porque la carga es instantánea, pero la cuestión es el UPDATE COMMAND, el cual es el siguiente:

> "UPDATE precios SET precio = ?precionueva, precio2 = ?precio2nueva,
>   costo = ?costonueva, ganancia = ?ganancianueva WHERE idproducto =
>   ?idnueva; UPDATE productos Set stockminimo = ?stockminimonueva,
>   categoria = IFNULL((Select id FROM categoriadeproductos WHERE nombre =
>   ?nombrecategoria), (SELECT id FROM categoriadeproductos LIMIT 1)),
>   proveedor = IFNULL((Select id FROM proveedores WHERE nombre =
>   ?nombreproveedor), (SELECT id FROM proveedores LIMIT 1)), cantidad =
>   ?cantidadnueva, nombre = ?nombrenuevo WHERE id = ?idnueva;"

Mi teoría, Realiza 3 consultas por registro, sin importar cual fue el parámetro que se modifico, es decir que si se modifico solo un parámetro, los demás que se están ejecutando, se están procesando de forma innecesaria.

Aquí la estructura de la base de datos:

**Tabla productos**

```
CREATE TABLE `productos` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nombre` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `tipodeproducto` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `cantidadbultocerrado` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `cantidadbultoabierto` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `especial` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `ultimamodificacion` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `ingresosbrutos` DECIMAL(3,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `categoria` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `proveedor` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `cantidad` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `stockminimo` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '4.00',
    `precio` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `costo` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `precio2` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `pesoprecio` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1.00',
    `fecha` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `codigobarras` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `imagen` BLOB NULL,
    `eliminado` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `id` (`id`),
    INDEX `eliminado` (`eliminado`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=9031
;
```

**Tabla Categorias de productos**

```
CREATE TABLE `categoriadeproductos` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nombre` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `ganancia` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=5
;
```

**Tabla precios**

```
CREATE TABLE `precios` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `porcentaje` DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `precio` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `precio2` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `ganancia` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `costo` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `idproducto` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `numerodepreciodelista` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `impuesto` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `ingresosbrutos` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `idproducto` (`idproducto`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=6149
;
```

**Tabla de proveedores**

```
CREATE TABLE `proveedores` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nombre` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `descripcion` TEXT NULL,
    `domicilio` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `localidad` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `telefono` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `fax` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `codigo postal` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `contacto` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=2
;
```

**Tabla codigobarras**

```
CREATE TABLE `codigobarras` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `idproducto` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `codigobarras` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `idrubro` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `idpromocion` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `idproducto` (`idproducto`),
    INDEX `idpromocion` (`idpromocion`),
    INDEX `idrubro` (`idrubro`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=9192
;
```

Y a continuacion el codigo que utilizo completo para realizar la actualizacion ya dicha:

```
'Declaracion de variables y objetos
public listadodeproductos As New DataGridView
Public datosdeproductos As New BindingSource
Private listadepreciosbinding As BindingManagerBase
Private listadodeproducto As New DataTable
'iniciar parametros al cargar el formulario
Private Sub ME_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AddHandler listadeproductosbinding.BindingComplete, AddressOf BindingComplete
    datosdeproductos.datasource = listadodeproducto
    listadeproductosbinding = me.bindingcontext(datosdeproductos, "listadodeproductos")
    listadodeproductos.DataSource = listadodeproductossource
    cargardatos
End Sub
'subrutina para guardar los cambios realizados en el datagridview (listadodeproductos)
sub Actualizardatos()
    datosdeproductos.EndEdit()
    listadeproductosbinding.EndCurrentEdit()
    listadodeproducto.GetChanges()
    ' abro la conexion con el servidor
    Using conexion As New MySqlConnection(conexionstring)
        conexion.Open()
        'declaro el adaptador para realizar el cambio en la base de datos
        Using adaptador As New MySqlDataAdapter
            adaptador.SelectCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT productos.id, productos.nombre AS Nombre,  categoriadeproductos.nombre AS Categoría, proveedores.nombre AS Proveedor, cantidad AS Cantidad, stockminimo AS ' Stock Mínimo ', (precios.precio) AS Precio, (precios.precio2) AS ' Precio % ', (precios.costo) AS ' P.costo ', (precios.ganancia) AS Ganancia, ultimamodificacion AS ' Fecha última modificación ', codigobarras.codigobarras AS ' Código de Barras ' FROM productos INNER JOIN precios ON precios.numerodepreciodelista = 0 AND precios.idproducto = productos.id INNER JOIN codigobarras ON codigobarras.idproducto = productos.id INNER JOIN (proveedores, categoriadeproductos) ON proveedores.id = productos.proveedor AND categoriadeproductos.id = productos.categoria WHERE productos.eliminado = 0 GROUP BY productos.id", conexion)
            adaptador.UpdateCommand = New MySqlCommand("UPDATE precios SET precio = ?precionueva, precio2 = ?precio2nueva, costo = ?costonueva, ganancia = ?ganancianueva WHERE idproducto = ?idnueva; UPDATE productos Set stockminimo = ?stockminimonueva, categoria = IFNULL((Select id FROM categoriadeproductos WHERE nombre = ?nombrecategoria), (SELECT id FROM categoriadeproductos LIMIT 1)), proveedor = IFNULL((Select id FROM proveedores WHERE nombre = ?nombreproveedor), (SELECT id FROM proveedores LIMIT 1)), cantidad = ?cantidadnueva, nombre = ?nombrenuevo WHERE id = ?idnueva;", conexion)
            adaptador.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("stockminimonueva", MySqlDbType.Decimal, 11.2, "Stock Mínimo")
            adaptador.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("cantidadnueva", MySqlDbType.Decimal, 11.2, "cantidad")
            adaptador.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("precionueva", MySqlDbType.Decimal, 11.2, "Precio")
            adaptador.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("precio2nueva", MySqlDbType.Decimal, 11.2, "Precio %")
            adaptador.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("costonueva", MySqlDbType.Decimal, 11.2, "P. costo")
            adaptador.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("ganancianueva", MySqlDbType.Decimal, 11.2, "Ganancia")
            adaptador.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("idnueva", MySqlDbType.Int32, 11, "id")
            adaptador.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("nombrecategoria", MySqlDbType.Text, 0, "Categoría")
            adaptador.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("nombreproveedor", MySqlDbType.Text, 0, "Proveedor")
            adaptador.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("nombrenuevo", MySqlDbType.Text, 0, "Nombre")
            listadodeproducto.GetChanges()
            adaptador.Update(listadodeproducto)
        End Using
    End Using
END SUB
Sub BindingComplete(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As BindingCompleteEventArgs)
    If e.BindingCompleteContext = BindingCompleteContext.DataSourceUpdate _
        AndAlso e.Exception Is Nothing Then     
        e.Binding.BindingManagerBase.EndCurrentEdit()
    End If
End Sub
'Cargar los datos de la base de datos al datatable
SUB cargardatos()
    Using conexion As New MySqlConnection(conexionstring)
        conexion.Open()
        ' declaro el adaptador para realizar el cambio en la base de datos
        Using adaptador As New MySqlDataAdapter
            adaptador.SelectCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT productos.id, productos.nombre AS Nombre,  categoriadeproductos.nombre AS Categoría, proveedores.nombre AS Proveedor, cantidad AS Cantidad, stockminimo AS 'Stock Mínimo', (precios.precio) AS Precio, (precios.precio2) AS 'Precio %', (precios.costo) AS 'P. costo', (precios.ganancia) AS Ganancia, ultimamodificacion AS 'Fecha última modificación', codigobarras.codigobarras AS 'Código de Barras' FROM productos INNER JOIN precios ON precios.numerodepreciodelista = 0 AND precios.idproducto = productos.id INNER JOIN codigobarras ON codigobarras.idproducto = productos.id INNER JOIN (proveedores, categoriadeproductos) ON proveedores.id = productos.proveedor AND categoriadeproductos.id = productos.categoria WHERE productos.eliminado = 0 GROUP BY productos.id", conexion)
            adaptador.Fill(listadodeproducto)
            listadodeproducto.tablename = "listadodeproductos"
        End Using
    End Using
END sub
```

Espero encontrar alguna forma de realizar una consulta mas optima para realizar la actualización. 
PD: los únicos datos que son modificables en el datagridview son los parámetros cargados en UPDATE COMMAND, el resto esta solo como READ ONLY

Comment: No entiendo porque tu update hace dos updates, parece un claro error de concepto. Si es un update, quiere decir que el dato existe. Es dificil que se elimine el proovedor de un producto (como esta descripto en la query) y estas buscando por nombre en dos tablas (cuando claramente deberias saber los Id de antemano porque deberia haber seleccionado los nombres en las pantallas). Faltaria que muestres las tablas proveedores y categoria de productos, ya que las tablas codigo de barras y precios en esa query no estan.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, tienes razón, agrego las tablas, y aclaro tambien ese punto. No necesito insertar un registro ni borrarlo, Ademas esta indexada la base de datos.

Comment: ok.. como primera medida, estas haciendo full scan de las tablas proveedores y categoria de productos, porque no hay indice por nombre, como estas buscando. Mas alla de eso, habria que ver si en tu form no hay forma de tomar esos datos directamente (el usuario elige el proovedor? entonces sabes el id de antemano, para que ir a buscarlo por nombre? lo mismo con la categoria de producto)

Comment: En el datagrid Se muestran todos los productos de la Base de datos, y cuando el usuario va a editar, Un autocomplete tiene ya los nombres disponibles de categoria y proveedor disponibles y cuando termina de editar la celda, una subrutina valida los datos ingresados, eso es sencillo, el problema esta en la actualizacion masiva, cuando edita muchos campos a la vez

Comment: porque un autocomplete y no un combo con los datos extraidos de la base de datos, donde deberias tener ya los id? y cual es el problema cuando edita masivamente, tal vez estas actualizando muchos registros y por eso tarda? igual hacer una busqueda por cada vez a la tabla proveedores por nombre, que no tiene indice, seguro va a tardar. prueba agregar los indices que te marque antes a ver si los tiempos mejoran.

Comment: pues es cierto puede ser un combobox, y no tarda demasiado en el momento de edicion, si tarda cuando se ejecuta la subrutina actualizardatos, y si ese asi esa es la cuestion tarda demasiado en actualizar. donde exactamente sugieres poner indices, porque yo pienso que ya estan bien los indices

Comment: Yo tuve un problema parecido, lo que hice para solventar ese problema fue actualizar por fila. Me explico, en el evento CellEndEdit() hacia el query del Update, entonces cuando un usuario editaba un valor de la fila, obtenia todos los datos de esa fila, y esos eran los parametros a actualizar, asi actualizaba por partes y no todo el datagrid, porque si tienes mas de 20mil registros es obvio que se va a tardar.

Comment: @BernardoHarreguy por los menos indices POR NOMBRE en las tablas donde buscas por nombre.

Comment: Fernando es una buena solución pero en este caso, el usuario tiene la posibilidad de actualizar todos los registros en un momento, quiero decir, puede editar uno o varios campos de todos los registros a la vez, por lo tanto esa solución no seria válida

Comment: Hace una semana que estoy trabajando bajo esta pregunta, y no logro encontrar solución, tal vez pasarme a una librería ORM, algo sencillo, he visto nhibernate, pero la verdad es que es demasiado cambio, por algo que quiero hacer bastante sencillo, simplemente que el SQL se genere de manera mas optima automáticamente, como primera idea, y que la actualización sea rápida, o realizar el procedimiento en segundo plano, o mejor aun, hacer un INSERT REPLACE, seria mas rápido, la verdad no lo se! Alguna otra idea? por favor ayudenme gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me voy a enfocar en lo que parece ser el principal problema que es el `UPDATE` de `productos`. Lo escribo con otro formato solo para tenerlo más claro:

```
UPDATE  productos 
    Set     stockminimo = ?stockminimonueva, 
        categoria = IFNULL((Select id FROM categoriadeproductos WHERE nombre = ?nombrecategoria), (SELECT id FROM categoriadeproductos LIMIT 1)), 
        proveedor = IFNULL((Select id FROM proveedores WHERE nombre = ?nombreproveedor), (SELECT id FROM proveedores LIMIT 1)), 
        cantidad = ?cantidadnueva, 
        nombre = ?nombrenuevo 
    WHERE id = ?idnueva;
```

El primer problema serio, es que estás buscando un `id` a partir de un nombre tanto en `categoriadeproductos` como en `proveedores`, tal como lo menciona @gbianchi si no tienes un índice sobre el nombre caerás en un `full scan` que podría ser sumamente costoso, dependiendo de la cantidad de registros.

Pero más allá de eso, esto es un problema de diseño: *¿Que ocurre si hay dos categorías con el mismo nombre?* *¿O dos proveedores que se llamen igual?*, el único que puede decidir cual corresponde es el usuario, por lo tanto debes guardar la selección que haga a nivel del `id` y no del `nombre`, no está de más recalcarlo, un `id` o `pk` o como quieras llamarlo es el dato que univocamente te identifica un registro. El usuario seleccionará un nombre de categoría o de proveedor, pero esa selección tiene que estar "atada" al `id` de cada dato, normalmente se le ofrece ver/buscar al usuario el `id` y el `nombre` de modo que sea él quien decida si quiere a `(1) - Empresa A` o `(2) - Empresa A`

Solucionando esto es todo más sencillo ya que lo que harías es:

```
UPDATE  productos 
    Set     stockminimo = ?stockminimonueva, 
        categoria = IFNULL(?id_categoria, ?valor_default_categoria), 
        proveedor = IFNULL(?id_proveedor, ?valor_default_proveedor), 
        cantidad = ?cantidadnueva, 
        nombre = ?nombrenuevo 
    WHERE id = ?idnueva;
```

Los valores `valor_default_categoria` y `valor_default_proveedor` si son valores que no cambian a menudo, Puedes:

- Pasarlos de manera "dura/hardcoded" (no es lo más elegante)
- Configuraralos en alguna tabla de parámetros de tu sistema y leerlos al inicio una única vez
- Agregar algún un `DEFAULT` a las columnas, algo así `categoria INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1` o `proveedor INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1`, en  ambos casos configuramos que el valor por defecto será `1` (elige el que corresponda)
- Pero si quieres usar tu consulta, te recomiendo invocarla una única vez (no con cada `UPDATE`) `SELECT id FROM proveedores order by id LIMIT 1`, yo le agregaría el `ORDER BY` para que siempre obtengas el primer id, no sé exactamente como se comporta MySql, en SQL Server al menos, sin el `ORDER BY` no tienes seguridad que la consulta siempre devuelva el mismo orden.
- No permitirle al usuario no seleccionar alguno de estos datos, y así evitas la necesidad de un valor por defecto

Comment: Hola patricio!! aprecio mucho tu respuesta!! tienes agumentos muy buenos, y la verdad es que mejora mucho la velocidad de la consulta, es cierto, pero el problema que utilizo el nombre, para poder realizar el muestro de los campos, proveedor y categoria, la solucion es acetada, el problema lo arrastro de la consulta SELECT, que esta aqui https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/96048/como-realizar-una-consulta-mas-r%C3%A1pida-mysql/96104#96104