# Los cambios realizados en una tabla temporal, ¿se ven reflejados en sus tablas originales?

Tags: mysql

Creo una Tabla temporal y le inserto datos de otras tablas. Si esos datos si son modificados, ¿dichas modificaciones son reflejados en sus tablas originales?

Aquí mi tabla temporal:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS categoriasaseleccionar; CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE categoriasaseleccionar (nombre TEXT) ;  INSERT INTO categoriasaseleccionar (nombre) VALUES ('Todas'); INSERT INTO categoriasaseleccionar (nombre) SELECT nombre FROM categoriadeproductos;
```

y realizo una update por ejemplo

```
UPDATE categoriasaseleccionar SET nombre = 'caramelos' WHERE nombre = 'caramelitos';
```

Suponiendo que los nombres nunca se repiten, que es la regla que tengo al ingresar un nuevo registro, ademas tiene KEY con su identificador, evito escribir los parámetros de las tablas, que en definitiva no es necesario en esta pregunta.

El cambio realizado a la nombrada, "caramelitos" por "caramelos", se ve reflejado en la tabla "categoriadeproductos"

Es simple la pregunta, pero fundamental para lo que estoy haciendo! espero respuesta muchas gracias!

Por cierto, ¿se puede realizar algo para hacer que se reflejen los cambios en caso de no poderse?

Comment: No, son dos tablas independientes, ningún cambio en una tabla se replicará en la otra. Saludos.

Comment: hay algo que se pueda hacer? para poder reflejar los cambios? como un view algo asi?

Comment: porque usas una tabla temporal, y despues le haces un update a la misma, y despues esperas que los cambios sobre ella se reflejen en otra.. es una idea medio rara. Quieres explicar porque haces eso? tal vez tu problema venga por otro lado...

Comment: gbianchi, Siempre estas comentando en mis preguntas! siempre quieres llegar a fondo, es por otra pregunta, quiero realizar un update command, sencillo, y no en una consulta dinamica, la pregunta a la que hago referencia es la siguiente https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/98632/optimizar-un-updatecommand-de-mysql-bajo-vb-net

Comment: Bernardo, el sentido de llenar datos en una temporal desde una tabla "normal" justamente es independizarse de esta última, sin duda un vista se acercaría más a lo que buscas. Si no debieras implementar triggers para `insert, update, delete` que "sincronicen" los datos de una tabla a otra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tabla temporal**

Las tablas temporales son completamente independientes de la estructura normal de tu base de datos, no tienen ninguna relación y sirven como un repositorio de datos simplemente.

Lo que significa que los cambios realizados en estas no afectaran los valores de las tablas de las cuales se han alimentado.

Puedes realizar un UPDATE a una tabla formal de tu base de datos con la información que se encuentra en la tabla temporal, por ejemplo:

```
Update MyTable2 m
SET m.field1 = ##MyTempTable.field1
FROM ##MyTempTable
WHERE m.field2 = ##MyTempTable.field2
```

Comment: Gracias! por tu respuesta tridam