# Estructura de tabla

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

me dirijo hacia ustedes con la intención de que me ayuden con una consulta, les comento primero que nada que se trata de la base de datos de un sistema supervisorio, en la cual tiene sensores de temperatura, presión y flujo..... y estos son almacenados cada medio segundo, esto debido a que se tiene que registrar cada valor de cada variable para luego ser mostrado en pantalla en tiempo real....

entonces en la base de datos tengo las siguientes tablas:

```
tabla termoscuplas:
    id_modulo   varchar(4) 
    descripcion     varchar(100)
    vin0    varchar(7) 
    vin1    varchar(7) 
    vin2    varchar(7)  
    vin3    varchar(7)
    vin4    varchar(7)  
    vin5    varchar(7) 
    vin6    varchar(7)  
    vin7    varchar(7) 
    fecha   date 
    hora    time    
    id_caldera  varchar(2)

Tabla Transmisores:
    id_modulo   varchar(4) 
    descripcion     varchar(100)
    vin0    varchar(7) 
    vin1    varchar(7) 
    vin2    varchar(7)  
    vin3    varchar(7)
    vin4    varchar(7)  
    vin5    varchar(7) 
    vin6    varchar(7)  
    vin7    varchar(7) 
    fecha   date 
    hora    time    
    id_caldera  varchar(2)
```

cada taba almacena alredor de 401,521 registros, y cada 7 dias se aplica un Clear a la base de datos....

en cada tabla vemos un campo vin0...hasta....vin7 esto implica que a cada campo esta asignado un sensor ya sea de temperatura y transmisor de flujo y presion....

he aplicado un inner join, de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT *
FROM termocuplas
INNER JOIN transmisores
ON termocuplas.id_caldera = transmisores.id_caldera
WHERE termocuplas.id_modulo = '3H'
```

la consulta funciona, pero esta tarda al rededor de 20 a 30 minutos, para luego ser mostrado en unas graficas, mi conflicto esta en que tarda demasiado, quisiera estructurar de forma mas eficiente, que me recomiendan???

cabe destacar que en cada tabla en el campo id_caldera, no es unico, ya que solo se almacena 'C1' o 'C2' indicando para que maquina.... y las tablas las tengo configuradas tal cual se las mostre, de forma sencillas.

Comment: No comprendo del todo el proceso, pero es mejor tener una tabla con el resumen de la información para mostrar las gráficas para evitar hacer esa gran consulta cada vez que requieras visualizar la información.  En su lugar cada vez que hagas el INSERT cada medio segundo actualizas la tabla de resumen con ese valor actualizado y te ahorras el tiempo para generar la consulta sobre todo el conjunto de datos. Espero me haya dado a entender.

Comment: Saludos! Canabix!.... yo habia pensado hacerla de esa forma, y ps por lo que estoy viendo es lo mejor que podria aplicar.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varios factores que no podre abarcar todos, pero te mencionaré los que considero te podrían ayudar.

**Punto uno**

**No estas usando llaves primarias**, generalmente las columnas llamadas ids son las llaves primarias de cada tabla en una base de datos, las llaves primarias agilizan las consultas porque se crean indices y estos indices son leidos mucho mas rapidos que una columna que no está *indexada*

*Mi consejo es que pongas los ids como tipo de dato numerico (int) y que sean llaves primarias.*

Aqui te dejo documentacion relacionado a [indices / llaves primarias](http://www.sgmendez.com/2011/10/04/tipos-indices-mysql/)

**Punto dos**

```
SELECT *
```

Cuando no especificas el nombre de las columnas de la tabla o tablas que estas consultando el Sistema Gestor de Base de Datos tiene que consultar los metadata de la tabla para entender que quieres todas las columnas de dicha tabla. Desconozco si esto lo hace para cada registro o si lo hace una sola vez cuando ejecutas la consulta.

*Por tanto, lo recomendable es que especifiques claramente el nombre de las columnas que deseas consultar*

Aquí está la documentación del SELECT * vs SELECT nombre_columna: https://bi-bigdata.com/2012/09/02/select-vs-select-in-sql-server-query/#more-297

**Punto tres**

Si vas a estar haciendo la consulta

```
SELECT *
FROM termocuplas
INNER JOIN transmisores
ON termocuplas.id_caldera = transmisores.id_caldera
WHERE termocuplas.id_modulo = '3H'
```

repetidas veces, lo mejor será que hagas una **vista (view)**, en resumen una vista es una tabla *imaginaria* que estructura la información de dos tablas o mas en una sola y agiliza el proceso de lectura.

Aqui te dejo documentacion relacionada a vistas en MySQL: https://www.anerbarrena.com/create-view-mysql-5101/

**Punto cuatro**

Considerando los **401,521 registros** y cerrandolo en **500,000 registros**, que son bastantes, vas a necesitar una computadora potente para procesar esta cantidad de registros, esto incluye configurar tu sistema gestor de base de datos (doy por sentado que es MySQL o MariaDB) intenta con una computadora de 8GB de 64 bits y asignale al sistema gestor de base de datos unos 2 o 3GB de RAM, aqui te dejo un tutorial para incrementar el uso de memoria RAM en MySQL / MariaDB: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDGx34nUuUE

*Tienes que configurar el uso de memoria RAM del sistema gestor de base de datos si quieres una respuesta mas rápida.*

**¿Porqué? 8 GB de RAM**, porque creo que estarás ejecutando otros programas en esa misma PC

**Punto cinco**

Si esto es un proyecto universitario te aconsejo que te acerces a un maestro sea bueno y sepa de la materia de base de datos o a un Ingeniero en Sistemas Computacionales para que te pueda ayudar a mejorar este proceso.

Anexaré un tema relacionado a este tema: [Como realizar una consulta mas rápida MYSQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/96048/como-realizar-una-consulta-mas-r%c3%a1pida-mysql?rq=1)

Comment: Milll gracais Reynald0!!!!  me  has ayudado mucho, aclarandome varios puntos con esa documentacion......

Comment: Esa persona que puso -1, solo le gusta ver arder el mundo.

Comment: @GersonAriasCardenas Puedes indicar mi respuesta como correcta si te ha servido.